# Replace multiple tabs by single tab in python

Tags: python, file-handling

I am a newbie in python programming. I am reading a tab separated file and would like to do an operation which can replace multiple tabs (separating two columns) by single tab.

```
with open('file.tsv','r') as fin:
    cr = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    filecontents = [line for line in cr]
```

I tried doing it by join function

```
with open('file.tsv','r') as fin:
    cr = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    filecontents = ''.join([line.replace('\t\t', '\t') for line in cr])
```

I am getting below error.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

How can I do it?

Comment: If your file is a well formatted tsv, two tabs mean that there's a column with blank value, if you remove one tab could make your tsv file lose consistency

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> re.sub

Giving it "[\t]+" is telling it find one or more tabs and replace it with 1.
Note the use of "\\" is to tell python its a special character.

```
import re
s = "a\\t\\t\\t\\t\\ta\\t\\t"
print (re.sub(r"[\\t]+", "\t", s))

output >>>
a   a
```

Answer (score 0):

One might use the `str.replace` method to ensure each line only contains a single tab in a row

```
filecontents = [line.replace('\t\t', '\t') for line in cr]
```

Comment: the above condition only replaces 2 tabs.. Maybe use it to match multiple tabs?

Comment: line.replace('\t\t', '\t') is giving error:                                                                       `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`